# How can a system application disable the "disable" button in the application manager?

Tags: android

I am making an application for a tablet that will be permanently attached to an embedded system that it controls, a "smart appliance" set-up. I would like to ensure that the application can never be disabled. That is, I want the "disable button" in the application manager to be disabled like it is for some other system applications. The application is signed with the system key and is installed in the system directory.

This is an unusual situation where the idea that the user should have control of what is happening on their device doesn't apply. The tablet primarily exists for the purpose of running this application and if it is disabled the embedded system will reset the tablet every two minutes until it is re-enabled. This would probably be confusing for the user and I'd like to prevent those service calls in advance.

Comment: Because that is a system app.4

Comment: Yes, my application is a system application. That alone doesn't prevent it from being disabled.